# Given a aws s3 bucketname and key of the object, how to get the last modified attribute value of that object?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to get the last modified attribute value of an object in s3 bucket. I'm currently trying to do the below:

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.lookup(bucketname)
for key in bucket :
    print(key.name, key.last_modified)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. And i'm not able to find any other solution which would help me to do this. I do not want to use a cli.  Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using an outdated version of `boto`. These days, you should use [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Using the **client method** (which maps 1:1 to AWS API calls), the code would be:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket-name')

for object in response['Contents']:
    print(object['Key'], object['LastModified'])
```

Using the **resource method** (which is more Pythonic), the code would be:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('bucket-name')

for object in bucket.objects.all():
    print(object.key, object.last_modified)
```

Comment: Thank you @John Rotenstein. Currently, we loop through all the objects.
Is there a way where the key can be specified and the last modified attribute of only that object is fetched. Ofcourse, this can be achieved by using some conditions check, but is there a way to do this using some API's ?

Comment: You can use: `resource.Object('bucket_name','key').last_modified` or `client.head_object(Bucket='bucket_name',Key='key')['LastModified']`

Comment: Thank you @John Rotenstein ... This is exactly what i needed.